# How can I open swift files in swift playground on the iPad?

Tags: ios, swift

For my internship, me and my friend need to make an iOS app. The thing is I don’t have MacBook to do it on. I only have an iPad. I know i can program iOS apps on the iPad but i couldn’t manage to open zip files that i have downloaden from the internet. The files are put automatically in the file’s app, but I can’t open the file from swift playgrounds. Is there a way for me to open the whole file in swift playgrounds, so i can test out the AR functionality from the apple demo?

Comment: You need to elaborate a little more, how are these zip files getting to playgrounds? Why do you need them?

Comment: So explain where the files are placed into your iPad app, and show the code that attempts to open the files.

Comment: @DuncanC there is no code that tries to open the file. Let’s say for example i wanna try to experiment with the ARKit from the apple demo. For me to be able to experiment with the demo, i have to download a zip file that get’s automatically placed in my file’s app. Now i want to open this folder in swift playground but can’t manage to do this

Comment: The phrase "my file's app" does not make sense to me. You mean your app's bundle?

Comment: It sounds like the files are resources that you are supposed to use to build the demo app. You may be out of luck on an iPad, since iPad playgrounds are limited in what they can do since iPads don't have an open file system or a full IDE.

Comment: There is a big difference in-between making Apps on an iPad and making apps on a Mac. A "zip" file from the internet is likely designed to work with full Xcode. You can't just put it in a playgrounds app. You can take Most of the files within and use them (drag and drop) in a playground app but the app is likely designed to work with Xcode not playgrounds.

Comment: https://medium.com/geekculture/realitykit-911-swift-playgrounds-or-how-to-create-and-debug-ar-apps-on-ipad-pro-190a6d2e03bb

Comment: in Swift Playgrounds go to "More Playgrounds" > Books > Augmented Reality

Comment: They also have "AR Create"